# Infinite products $f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x^n)$ and $g(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, special-functions, infinite-product

Consider the functions

$
f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x^n)
$

and

$
g(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x^n)
$

$f(x)$ is defined for $x\in[-1,1]$ and $g(x)$ is defined for $x\in[-1,0]$.

I was wondering if there was a different/better way to express these functions, such as a closed-form expression/power series.

[Desmos screenshot ($f(x)$ in red and $g(x)$ in blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUsmA.png)

Edit: As pointed out by [donaastor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/251847/donaastor)
the [Pentagonal Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) can be used to express $f(x)$ as a power series.

Edit 2: The [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) $\phi(x)$ seems similar to $f(x)$ but with a different domain. For $\phi(x)$ the domain is $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem

Comment: Thanks. It is really interesting how the pentagonal numbers can be used to express $f(x)$.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question? (I'm asking so that I can better understand the site expectations for questions.)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function

Comment: I don't think I see any reference into beautifying the expression for $g(x)$, so maybe you will find useful that $f(−x)g(x^2)=f(x)g(x)^2$ or $f(x)g(x)=f(x^2)$ or $g(-x)f(x^2)=f(x)g(x^2)$ which you can get by expanding the product for $f(-x)$ and $g(-x)$. You can play with more substitutions and more products and derive more equations. I don't know in what context you need a nicer expression for these functions.

Comment: I believe I found a power series for $g(x)$ on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)
It states that:
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }q(n)x^{n}=\prod _{k=1}^{\infty }(1+x^{k})$
where $q(n)$ is the number of strict partitions of n.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that for $x\in(-1,1)$ we have $-1<x^n<1$, so $0<1-x^n<2$.
Thus
$$f(x)=\left|\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^n)\right|=\prod_{n\ge1}|1-x^n|=\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^n).$$
Furthermore,
$$f(x)g(x)=\prod_{n\ge1}(1+x^n)(1-x^n)=\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^{2n})=f(x^2),$$
so $g(x)=f(x^2)/f(x)$.

These functions don't have closed forms in terms of elementary functions, but they are extensively studied for their number-theoretic properties. We will consider their series expansions.

It is the case that these functions have a lot of significance in the study of [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). Specifically, they are related to generating functions of specific kinds of partitions. I'll demonstrate a general result and show how it relates to these functions.

**Theorem:** *Let $T\subseteq\Bbb N$ be nonempty and let $p_T(n)$ be equal to the number of integer partitions of a positive integer $n$ into parts all belonging to $T$ (also known as $T$-partitions of $n$). Then the generating function of $p_T(n)$ is given by
$$P_T(q):=\sum_{n\ge0}p_T(n)q^n=\prod_{k\in T}\frac{1}{1-q^k},\tag{$\star$}$$
where $|q|<1$.*

Immediately you will see that when $T=\Bbb N$, $P_{\Bbb N}(q)=1/f(q)$, and $g(q)=P_{\Bbb N}(q)/P_{\Bbb N}(q^2)$. In this case, $P_{\Bbb N}(q)$ is the generating function for the total number of partitions of $n$. The proof of the result is at the end of this answer.

Since $P(x)=1/f(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}p(n)x^n,$ we have that if $f(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}f_nx^n$ then
$$P(x)f(x)=\frac1{f(x)}f(x)=1=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(k)f_{n-k}.$$
This gives
$$p(0)=f_0=1,\qquad\qquad \sum_{k=0}^np(k)f_{n-k}=0\qquad n\ge1.$$
As others noted, this is the pentagonal number theorem, and $f_n=(-1)^k$ when $n=k(3k-1)/2$ and $0$ otherwise.

As for $g(q)=f(q^2)/f(q)=P(q)/P(q^2)$, we will examine $P(q)$ again. Note that
$$\begin{align}
P(q)=\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{1-q^n}&=\frac{1}{1-q}\frac{1}{1-q^2}\frac{1}{1-q^3}\frac{1}{1-q^4}\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1-q^2}\frac{1}{1-q^4}\frac{1}{1-q^6}\cdots\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-q}\frac{1}{1-q^3}\frac{1}{1-q^5}\cdots\right)\\
&=\left(\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{1-q^{2k}}\right)\left(\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{1-q^{2k-1}}\right)\\
&=P(q^2)\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{1-q^{2k-1}}.
\end{align}$$
Thus $$g(q)=\frac{P(q)}{P(q^2)}=\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{1-q^{2k-1}}.$$
Note however that if we write $O=\{2k-1:k\in\Bbb N\}$ to be the set of odd positive integers, we get that
$$g(q)=\prod_{k\in O}\frac{1}{1-q^k}.$$
Applying the above theorem, $g(q)$ is seen to be the generating function for partitions of $n$ into odd parts.

---

*Proof.* Consider the series expansion of the product in $(\star)$. From the geometric series, we obtain
$$\prod_{k\in T}\frac{1}{1-q^k}=\prod_{k\in T}\left(\sum_{n\ge0}q^{nk}\right).$$
Since $T\subseteq\Bbb N$, we have $k\ge1$, and thus the sums on the right converge absolutely, and we are justified in expanding the product as
$$\prod_{k\in T}\left(\sum_{n\ge0}q^{nk}\right)=\sum_{n_1,n_2,n_3,...} q^{n_1k_1}q^{n_2k_2}q^{n_3k_3}\cdots=\sum_{n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3},...}\prod_{k\in T}q^{n_kk},\tag1$$
where the sum is over all $n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3},...\ge0$, and we have written $T=\{k_1,k_2,k_3,...\}$.

Suppose that $T$ is finite. Then write $T=\{k_1,...,k_m\}$ to obtain
$$\prod_{k\in T}\frac{1}{1-q^k}=\sum_{n_1,...,n_m\ge0}q^{n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_mk_m}.\tag2$$
We will use this later.

In the case that $T$ is infinite, we consider the limit
$$\prod_{k\in T}q^{n_kk}=\lim_{i\to\infty}q^{n_1k_1}q^{n_2k_2}\cdots q^{n_ik_i}=\lim_{i\to\infty}q^{n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_ik_i}.$$
To evaluate this limit we must consider the behavior of the sequence $(n_i)_{i\ge1}=(n_1,n_2,n_3,...)$. If it converges to zero, then there is some $j\ge1$ such that $i> j\Rightarrow n_i=0$. In this case
$$i>j\Rightarrow n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_jk_j+...=n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_jk_j,$$
which gives $$\prod_{k\in T}q^{n_kk}=\lim_{i\to\infty}q^{n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_jk_j}=q^{n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_jk_j}.$$
In the case that $(n_i)_{i\ge1}$ does not converge to $0$, the sum $n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_ik_i$ grows without bound. Since $|q|<1$, we have
$$\prod_{k\in T}q^{n_kk}=\lim_{i\to\infty}q^{n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_ik_i}=\lim_{i\to\infty}q^i=0.$$
So we only need to consider the cases of $(n_i)_{i\ge1}$ with a finite number of nonzero terms. That is,
$$\prod_{k\in T}\frac{1}{1-q^k}=\sum_{m\ge0}\sum_{n_1,...,n_m\ge0}q^{n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_mk_m}.\tag3$$
So, regardless of the size of $T$, we are taking a sum of $q^N$, where $N\ge0$ is an integer and it can be written as $N=n_1k_1+n_2k_2+...+n_mk_m$ for some choice of $(n_i,k_i)$. Clearly, this is an integer partition of $N$. Examining this partition, we see
$$n_1k_1+n_2k_2+..+n_mk_m=\underbrace{k_1+k_1+...+k_1}_{n_1\text{ times}}+...+\underbrace{k_m+k_m+...+k_m}_{n_m\text{ times}},$$
revealing that this is a partition of $N$ into parts belonging to $T$, as $k_i\in T$. We may reindex the sums $(2),(3)$ in terms of N, and get that they are both equal to
$$\prod_{k\in T}\frac{1}{1-q^k}=\sum_{N\ge0}\sum_{N=n_1k_1+...+n_rk_r}q^N=\sum_{N\ge0}q^N\sum_{N=n_1k_1+...+n_rk_r}1.$$
The quantity $\sum_{N=n_1k_1+...+n_rk_r}1$ clearly counts the number of partitions of $N$ into parts belonging to $T$. That is,
$$\prod_{k\in T}\frac{1}{1-q^k}=\sum_{n\ge0}p_T(n)q^n=P_T(q).$$ This completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

The power series
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^n) = (x,x)_\infty = f(-x,-x^2) = f(-x) $$
where $f()$ is the [Ramanujan theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function).
This power series is the ordinary generating function of
[OEIS sequence A010815](https://oeis.org/A010815) which
you can read for much more information. The infinite
product and the power series both converge exactly when
$x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
Their reciprocal is the generating function for all
integer partitions.

Now $(1+x) = (1-x^2)/(1-x)$ which implies
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty
 (1-x^{2n})/(1-x^n) = (x^2,x^2)_\infty/(x,x)_\infty.$$
Again, the infinite product and power series both converge
exactly when $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
This power series is the ordinary generating function of
[OEIS sequence A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009) which
you can read for much more information including its
interpretation as partitions into distinct parts.